# Deprecated: Function ereg()

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function ereg() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489151/function-ereg-is-deprecated)

I understand that in the new version of PHP `ereg` is deprecated:

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated

The code below worked fine in the old PHP. So I replaced `ereg` with `preg_match` and I am now getting the following error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '{' in

Here is my code...

```
if (!empty($searchval))
{
    if(ereg("[0-9]{5}", $searchval)) {
        $zip = $searchval;
    }
    else {
        $city = $searchval;
    }
} else
{
    $error .= "<div id='Error'>Please enter zip</div>";
    $zip = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(preg_match("~\d{5}~", $searchval)) {
```

Left code stays the same

Comment: Brilliant! your my hero.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_*()` need a delimiter for the regex.

In most cases, `/` is used, but you may use anything, so long as they match. `~` and `@` are common, because they are unlikely to appear in most regexes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the regular expression with a delimiter like:

```
if(preg_match("/[0-9]{5}/", $searchval)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included a delimiter in your regular expression.  Try this:

```
if (!empty($searchval))
{
    if(ereg("/[0-9]{5}/", $searchval)) {
    $zip = $searchval;
    }
    else {
    $city = $searchval;
    }
} else
{
    $error .= "<div id='Error'>Please enter zip</div>";
    $zip = false;
}
```